# How to put data in separate new columns csv using java?

Tags: java, csv

How can I go to new line in created .csv file. I can only go to next cell using ";"

```
File temp = new File("results11234.csv");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < dirs2.size(); i++) {
    try {
        writer.append(dirs.get(i)+ ';');

        writer.append((Integer.toString(dirs2.get(i)) + ';')); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    }
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();
```

Comment: I can't understand. post your current output, and desired output

Comment: Make use of a didicated library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a line break:

```
writer.append("\n");   // for unix
writer.append("\r\n"); // for windows
```

If you want to be platform independent, you can do:

```
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
...
writer.append(lineSep);
```

Or you use the BufferedWriter (the best way i think):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
...
writer.newLine();
```

I hope, it helps